# PHP5 static methods inheritance. Overloading. Getting called class name

Tags: php, oop, static

I have good oop understanding but poor understanding of its implementation in php...

I have the following code, hope it's self documented =).

I need to have `BB` in the output

```
class A{
    // I can't copy function::classname() to all my descendant classes

    static function classname(){
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
}

class B extends A{

    static function test(){
        self::classname();
    }

    function test1(){
        self::classname();
    }



    //i have A LOT of static and non-static functions using self::classname() in their code
    // I can't copy all them to base class
    }

    $v = new B();
    B::test();
    $v->test1();
```

I'm stuck with `static::` and `self::` syntax

---

PS: another crazy question I've come across:

Suppose I have

```
function doSomething(){
    echo $this->id;
}
```

Sometimes it gets into the static contexts. Yes, I know, that's because my bad application design. But is it possible to create a second(mirror, overloading) function

```
static function doSomething(){
    echo false;
}
```

It means that using
`$obj->doSomething()` returns `id` and using `Class::doSomething()` returns `false`

---

Question 3:

Is it possible to get property default value in static context an property value in non-static context automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [late static binding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php).

```
class A {
    static function classname() {
        echo __CLASS__;
    }

    static function test1() {
        static::classname();
    }
}

class B extends A {
    static function classname() { 
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
}

$v = new B();
B::test1();
$v->test1();
```

Or as pointed out by **Long Ears** in the comments, assuming php 5.3.0+ you can use `get_called_class()`

```
class A {
    static function classname() {
        echo get_called_class();
    }

    // this can be defined in either class A or B without affecting the output
    static function test1() {
        static::classname();
    }
}

class B extends A {
}

$v = new B();
B::test1();
$v->test1();
```

Outputs:

```
BB
```

Comment: doesn't this example output `AA`?

Comment: My bad, updated the question. You need to use late static binding.

Comment: If you want to get the called class in classname() without implementing it again in the child, you can change it from `echo __CLASS__;` to `echo get_called_class();` (Requires PHP >= 5.3.0 like LSB)

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not what I want. The last edit explains why

Comment: @LongEars Would it be difficult for you to post the entire solution?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your second "crazy" question, see the [Magic Methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods). Basically, you would need to implement something like:

```
class Foo
{
  public function __call($name, $arguments)
  {
    // call the _$name function
  }

  public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments)
  {
    // call the _{$name}_static function
  }

  private function _bar()
  {
  }

  private static function _bar_static()
  {
  }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->bar();
Foo::bar();
```

Answer (score 0):

it's possible to add a static method like this

> ```
> class Foo {   
> public static function __callStatic()   {
> // ....     
> }
> }
>
> // in Other file 
>
> // Call the static method   
> Foo-->__callStatic()
> ```

and call it on an other file (In php ) ?